# How do i fix VLC importing issues? (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, video, vlc, traceback

I am trying to make a simple youtube video player, however i am having issues i dont know how to deal with.
code:

```
import vlc
import pafy
#################################################
url = "https://www.youtube.com/c/pyrocynicalvevo"
video = pafy.new(url)
best = video.getbest()
media = vlc.MediaPlayer(best.url)
media.play()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\RUBY\ythandler.py", line 1, in <module>
    import vlc
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 220, in <module>
    dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 180, in find_lib
    dll = ctypes.CDLL('.\\' + libname)
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 344, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

im on 64 bit windows 11 pc running the code on sublime.

any help is greatly appreciated. i did pip install pafy and pip install python-vlc, aswell as pip3 install python-vlc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do i get this error: "OSError: \[WinError 126\] The specified module could not be found"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64082873/why-do-i-get-this-error-oserror-winerror-126-the-specified-module-could-not)

Comment: Or [Python - unable to import vlc module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060906/python-unable-to-import-vlc-module) ? Both I found when I searched for "dlopen vlc windows unable to open"